# Is it possible to set up a mechanism in a smart contract that periodically iterates over a list without being triggered by a transaction?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I want my smart contract to offer a refund service. It must periodically check the start date of a reservation stored in a list of strucutures and if it coincides with the current date, a control mechanism starts.Is it possible in solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Smart contract cannot do any work on their own. They have to be always triggered by some transaction.

How this kind of things are usually done is that you offer a `withdraw` function which users can call and it will calculate whether they should be sent something. Or, if you prefer pushing the assets, you can create a function which anyone can call which pushes the assets to all required participants - but this doesn't probably scale well (may run out of gas).

Comment: thanks, now I understand. I asked another more specific question and I was wondering if you could help me [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92867/interaction-between-smart-contract-and-oracle-contract)